# Can't access my Apps page in MS Teams (and update my custom app)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to make a MS Teams app using the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/learn/modules/embedded-web-experiences/3-exercise-create-custom-teams-personal-tab

I managed to add my app to MS Teams and got it to work. 
However, when I updated the code, deleted the app in MS Teams and tried adding the updated version, it would give me a `Something went wrong` notification.

Now, I'm not able to open the **App Studio** app or the **Apps** page. It'll just non-stop load, but nothing shows up.

### Things that I've tried

- Restart MS Teams
- Restart MS Teams in admin mode
- Under `%AppData%\Microsoft\Teams` clear the following folders: `blob_storage`, `Cache` and `GPUCache`

### Expected result

When I click the `Apps` button, the Apps page should open and show me all the apps, so I can navigate and add my own custom app.

### Actual result

- Pressing `App Studio` button does nothing. The button will be in a "pressed" state, but nothing shows up
- [image]
- [image]

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Luckily not! Also read somewhere that there was indeed some issues with the App (store) from Teams. No more issues here :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this also - my suspicion is Teams is being affected by the very large volume of users working remotely, and certain portions are being, let's say, "stress tested" more than usual.

Comment: But I doubt this has to do with stress testing since the App store thing works perfectly fine on a different device, but when I add the app and re-add the app, the store is broken.

Comment: I'm just joking about "stress-testing" - what I mean is that the entire "Teams" service is overloaded. I'm seeing the same as you - my app is working fine in one tenant, but in another tenant ALL apps are broken, mine and others.